# In DQN, hwo to perform gradient descent when each record in experience buffer corresponds to only one action?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The DQN algorithm below

[image]

[Source](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/rl-dqn-deep-q-network-e207751f7ae4)

At the gradient descent line, there's something I don't quite understand.

For example, if I have 8 actions, then the output Q is a vector of 8 components, right?

But for each record in D, the return y_i is only a scalar with respect to a given action. How can I perform gradient descent on (y_i - Q)^2 ? I think it's not guaranteed that within a minibatch I have all actions' returns for a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the loss only on the Q-value which its action is selected. In your example, assume for a given row in your mini-batch, the action is `3`. Then, you obtain the corresponding target, `y_3`, and then the loss is `(Q(s,3) - y_3)^2`, and basically you set the loss value of other actions to zero. You can implement this by using `gather_nd` in `tensorflow` or by obtaining `one-hot-encode` version of actions and then multiplying that `one-hot-encode` vector to Q-value vector. Using a `one-hot-encode` vector you can write:

```
action_input = tf.placeholder("float",[None,action_len])
QValue_batch = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(T_Q_value,action_input), reduction_indices = 1)
```

in which `action_input = np.eye(nb_classes)[your_action (e.g. 3)]`. Same procedure can be followed by `gather_nd`: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd

I hope this resolves your confusion.